# tableview cell disappears when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tablecellrenderer, reuseidentifier

This problem does not necessarily occur

Sometimes it disappears when sliding and sometimes does not disappear

#### more information here

[click to show gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua6ss.gif)

[click to show storyboard png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFcJq.png)

#### code

```
HSubjectCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kSubjectCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
_subjectView = cell;
cell.delegate = self;
cell.subject = self.subjectArr[indexPath.section - 3];
return cell;
```

Comment: No idea what could be causing this - perhaps a constraint issue? Have you tried using the view debugger when the cell disappears to see if it has any useful information on the view hierarchy?

Comment: 1.First debug without real data, 2.  If u r using table view cell automatic dimension then debug with constant cell height and also debug with removing the cell constraints.

Comment: @RoboticCat [photos](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipO9AK-ZIEY941Wis5bDU6J5p25zmbmnwNGTGD0Y-Z2Xyt0qYub9ba1LebMfaM1aew?key=RVNRQjVVYnItQnZ4UXhQWUVvLXFiQkh5TWpzZWpB)

Comment: @iTamilan 1. heightForRowAtIndexPath-->return deviceWidth * 0.97 + 46; 2. heightForRowAtIndexPath-->return UITableViewAutomaticDimension; bug no result, the problem persists. I'm sure cell constraints are correct  [photos](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipO9AK-ZIEY941Wis5bDU6J5p25zmbmnwNGTGD0Y-Z2Xyt0qYub9ba1LebMfaM1aew?key=RVNRQjVVYnItQnZ4UXhQWUVvLXFiQkh5TWpzZWpB)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table views "hide" subviews the instant that cell's frame go out of view of the scroll view.

**An simple example on how table views work**

Let's say you define your row to have a height of `100.0f`. You add a simple `UIView` to it (let's say it has an orange background colour), which pins its edges perfectly to each edge of that `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`.

When you scroll that view up/down far enough so the `100.0f` height is above/below the scroll view's frame, that row is essentially hidden. This is to make the table view snappy and efficient.

**What you are experiencing**

Let's use the previous example, though instead of pinning the bottom of the subview to the bottom of the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`, you make it go `50.0f` over the bottom of the `contentView`, therefore being outside of the `UITableViewCell`.

You'll notice, if you scroll the orange `UIView` so it goes towards the top, that it disappears even though there is still some orange showing on the screen.

*But why is this happening?*

Because the subview you added does not fit within the `UITableViewCell`, when that cell scrolls out of view (based on its frame), it "disappears". Along with it disappearing, your subviews will too.

**How do I fix this?**

Ensure that all of your subviews are within the frame of the `UITableViewCell` which it is added to.

A simple way to see these bounds making the background colour of your `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView` a colour that stands out, such as `[UIColor orangeColor];`. Then you'll better understand how the frames are all relating.

Comment: It's alright, I'll try to make it clearer. Unfortunately those photos are showing 404 for me, can you try another way to share them?

Comment: [photos](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipO9AK-ZIEY941Wis5bDU6J5p25zmbmnwNGTGD0Y-Z2Xyt0qYub9ba1LebMfaM1aew?key=RVNRQjVVYnItQnZ4UXhQWUVvLXFiQkh5TWpzZWpB)

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Is there somewhere in your code where you are modifying the frames or sizes of your cells somehow? As well, does the frame size of your table view match your view controller's/root view's?

Comment: Thanks for your tips(_where you are modifying the frames or sizes of your cells_ ), Maybe I know the cause of the problem, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  **many requests** ,  and `reloadSection` when completed, frames of cells were madified

Comment: This is helpful. I add a uiview as separator line of table cell, found it is disappear when scrolling up/down. No I constraint it to bottom anchor of cell, the issue is fixed. `separatorLine.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)` .